# Offset phase angle of AC mains?

Tags: capacitor, ac, inductor

Using analog circuitry, is there a way to offset the phase angle of a single phase AC voltage while maintaining the same RMS voltage?

Comment: search "power factor correction".

Comment: Vicky, you need to be more clear. A phase angle is measured between two things, but you only mention one thing, the voltage. Maybe you mean the phase between current and voltage? Or maybe you mean the phase between the voltage on the input of your device and the voltage on the output. Or maybe you mean the phase angle between your voltage, and your neighbors. Anyway, a curios question.

Comment: Oops, I meant "maintaining the same RMS voltage."

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Providing you don't want excessive amounts of power use a series inductor and a capacitor down to the return path from the inductor output. Depending on values, you should be comfortably be able to lag the voltage a few degrees: -

[image]

It's probably advisable to put a resistor of a few tens of ohms in series with the inductor in case of AC transients causing a resonant overshoot and possible destruction of the capacitor. The circuit forms a 2nd order low pass filter and there are plenty of examples on the internet about its general phase angle performance like [this](http://sim.okawa-denshi.jp/en/RLCtool.php). I entered R=330\$\Omega\$ L = 100mH and C = 4.7uF. I reckon there was a lag of about 3º at 50Hz.

Using this technique to get leading output voltages is more tricky as you will need a relatively large inductor. Probably not advisable.

Whatever method you ultimately use you'll need to calculate currents and power disippation for the resistor.

Comment: How does one lag it 90 degrees?

Comment: If you choose L and C to resonate at your ac frequency it will introduce 90 deg shift but remember my comment about adding series resistance. Bit late aren't you lol.